# Symfony variable between 2 modules

Tags: symfony1

I want to pass variable from 1 module to another whit link.
 Example:

```
<?php echo link_to('questions','questions/index?testId='.$this->getId()); ?>
```

After this i take  variable whit action :

```
$this->testId = $request->getParameter('testId');
```

Ist work, but i want to use this variable all the time in this module in NEW and Edit.
If i work in this way i need to change link for new and edit somting like this:

```
<?php echo link_to('New Question','questions/new?testId='.$testId); ?>
```

And evriting is work but..

My question is : is have easier way to do this? Becose this way is slow and i think its not very right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to provide a parameter to your controller, there's no other way. You have to give it in an URL parameter.

You could put it in the user session but it will cause unexpected behaviours when the user opens several browser tabs with different IDs...

So URL parameter is the good way.